# DiscordAPIError[10002]: Unknown Application

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, application-error

I've ran into an error, but I have no idea where's the problem.
Please help me find the problem.
There's is what it got me as error:
*There was an error: DiscordAPIError[10002]: Unknown Application*

And here's the code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { REST, Routes, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');


const commands = [

    {
        name: 'embed',
        description: 'Sends an embed!', 
        options: [
            {
                name: 'title',
                description: 'Title of embed',
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                required: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'description',
                description: 'The description of embed',
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                required: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'color',
                description: 'The color of embed',
                type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
                required: false,
                choices: [
                    {
                        name: 'red',
                        value: 'ED4245',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'green',
                        value: '57F287',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'blue',
                        value: '3498DB',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'yellow',
                        value: 'FFFF00',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'white',
                        value: 'FFFFFF',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'gold',
                        value: 'F1C40F',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'orange',
                        value: 'E67E22',
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
];
```

Finding a solution to fix this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you are passing the wrong `client ID`. Make sure to use the  `client ID` you get from the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/1092703281836478564/oauth2/general) in the `oauth2` section and pass it as a string. Also, make sure that when registering the commands as [Guild Commands](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#guild-commands) you pass the `guild ID` as a string.

Comment: Damn. I checked everything I could, but I absolutely forgot about the client ID. I accidentally replaced client ID with guild ID. Thanks.